# How can I hide the PHP output of code 500 errors in AJAX calls?

Tags: php, ajax

When there is an AJAX request to an endpoint I'm making and inside that endpoint there is a PHP error (undefined variable, for example), it can leak critical data, because when an endpoint is called and it hits a fatal error, the output of that error is automatically passed to the front-end. If I simply hide this from the user, it's no good, an attacker can still force an error in order to read data from the endpoint.

Exactly how do I architecture around not leaking any details when a 500 error happens?

Here's code that would generate an error, or rather, output, if it was to be inside an endpoint:

```
$stored_secure_keys = [];
$stored_secure_keys['my_newly_generated_key_i_need_to_check'];
```

Here's the error it ouputs:

```
[27-Dec-2019 23:12:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: my_newly_generated_key_i_need_to_check in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\my-framework\Framework\Init.php on line 51
```

This is seen in the `Response` of that request I made to the endpoint.

Comment: Are you developing in production? Your php ini should turn off error reporting in your production server

Comment: @TimMorton I am in development as of now. Error reporting is vital, even on customer websites, is there no way to turn off error output but keep error logging?

Comment: @TimMorton I turned off `display_startup_errors` and `display_errors` but the output is still there.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting

Answer (score 0):

Check with status :

```
xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        // success

    }
};
```

Comment: My issue is that PHP-related errrors are sent in this request you're trying to check for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore errors and warnings put "error_reporting(0)" in top of you php file :

```
<?php    
error_reporting(0);

$stored_secure_keys = [];
$stored_secure_keys['my_newly_generated_key_i_need_to_check'];

// Error will not be shown or returned
```

[PHP documentation for more informations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)